# TSQL Merge Hint on target

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge

I have been doing a lot of reading on MERGE and just about every article I run across talks about concurrency issues and primary key violations when not using a table hint.  This particular query will not be in a concurrent environment but I wanted to test the syntax.  I recently put together a short script example to help another developer out but could not figure out why it wasn't parsing.

Can anyone shed light on this?

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Test CHAR(1))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Test CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @Table2 (Test) VALUES ('A'),('B')


MERGE INTO @Table1 WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS T 
USING @Table2 AS S
ON (T.ID = S.ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Test) VALUES (S.Test)
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
```

**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.**

- Syntax appears to be what the msdn is asking for: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)
- This guys link sort of confirms the syntax [SO LINk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810814/sql-merge-statements-on-tables-with-foreign-keys-and-resolving-deadlocks)
- The only thing I can think of is the ability to have a table lock on a table variable?

Comment: I did just confirm that this behavior is not consistent when using hash or physical tables under the same context defined above.  It seems to be isolated to the table variable.

Comment: Possibly a similar issue?  http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/with-nolock-and-table-vars.15855/.  I would really like to see the grounds the guy commenting about table variables not supporting locking.  MSDN doesn't seem to turn up anything that definitive as his statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending half an hour I realized that table **HINT** works only with *permanent & temporary tables* but not with *table variables!!!*

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1  (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Test CHAR(1))
CREATE TABLE #Table2  (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Test CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #Table2 (Test) VALUES ('A'),('B')

MERGE INTO #Table1  WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS T 
USING #Table2 AS S
ON (T.ID = S.ID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT   (Test)  VALUES (S.Test) 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;

SELECT * FROM #Table1

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```

Please check this query.